# HttpClient Request never ends when server didn't responde (iOS device with network link conditioner - 100% loss )

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, dotnet-httpclient

I'm facing an error that is driving me crazy.

My Xamarin application uses HttpClient to do requests(timeout 10 seconds). 
I found out that the iOS device on the developer settings with 100% loss of network link conditioner, after some time the request(s) get stuck  and never returns.

When I analyse where the tasks are stuck, I see that are stuck on `ServicePoint.cs:267`  on the `lock` statement of this code:

```
internal void SendRequest (WebOperation operation, string groupName)
{
        lock (this) {
            Scheduler.SendRequest (operation, groupName);
        }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out why this happens?

Comment: You are not using the HttpClient "Managed Provider" are you? I have only seen this behavior in the managed provider, which for security reasons you should not be using it anyway. Use the NSUrlSession provider and the httpclient will timeout normally vs. getting hang.

Comment: I checked and the answer is yes, I'm  using a "managed provider". I will try with NSUrlSession provider.  thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay doing feedback. Changing to NSUrlSession worked perfectly. Thank you .

Comment: Glad to hear it... 